# JSONObject getString returns null on first run

Tags: java, json, for-loop

I have this `String data = "[ {\"pname\":\"7\", \"qty\":\"222\"}, {\"pname\":\"8\", \"qty\":\"5\"}, {\"pname\":\"10\", \"qty\":\"65\"}, ]" ;`
which is on array list, I want to put them on the variable on each loop and save it to the database, but for now I do this code for debugging purpose because at the first loop of the code it is suuposed to output "qty" value but instead it is a null like this `{"pname":"7","qty":"222"}    null` but on the next run of loop it outputs this `{"pname":"8","qty":"5"}    222` it seems that on the second loop the first objects qty value is then taken on the second loop, the final output is this 
`{"pname":"7","qty":"222"}    null  {"pname":"8","qty":"5"}    222  {"pname":"10","qty":"65"}    5`

and this is the code that I have

```
 String data = "[ {\"pname\":\"7\", \"qty\":\"222\"}, {\"pname\":\"8\", \"qty\":\"5\"}, {\"pname\":\"10\", \"qty\":\"65\"}, ]" ;
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        ArrayList<HashMap> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
        String txtPname = "", txtQty = "";
        if (jsonArray == null) {
            System.out.println("json is empty");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    txtPname = item.put("pname",            jsonObject.getString("pname"));
                    txtQty = item.put("qty", jsonObject.getString("qty"));
                    output.append(jsonObject).append("    ");
                    output.append(txtQty).append("  ");
            }

        }
```

can anyone help me about this? any help will be so much appreciated, Thanks!!!

Comment: Please add the loop you are using.

Comment: @Markus Deibei, yeah I added it, I edited the post immediately. please see the code above, thanks

Comment: Your output and the loop don't fit. The line `jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);` should always refer to the same object in the list. This should probably be `jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);`

Comment: yeah that is exactly what my loop is currently only when I put it on this question I got typo for that for, sorry it was actually I but still the output is the same

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning wrong value to txtQty rather than the current value in the JSONObject:

HashMap `Put` Method (From Docs):

Returns:

> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no
>   mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key.)

Thats why you are getting null at first attempt and 222 at second.

Following code will give you desired result:

```
 String data = "[ {\"pname\":\"7\", \"qty\":\"222\"}, {\"pname\":\"8\", \"qty\":\"5\"}, {\"pname\":\"10\", \"qty\":\"65\"}, ]" ;
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        ArrayList<HashMap> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
        String txtPname = "", txtQty = "";
        if (jsonArray == null) {
            System.out.println("json is empty");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    txtPname = item.put("pname",            jsonObject.getString("pname"));
                    txtQty = item.put("qty", jsonObject.getString("qty"));
                    output.append(jsonObject).append("    ");
                    output.append(jsonObject.getString("qty")).append("  ");
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't quite follow, can you give me sample codes please? thnaks

Comment: The line `txtQty = item.put("qty", jsonObject.getString("qty"));` does not add the current value of `jsonObject.getString("qty")` into the Hashmap and then return it, but rather returns the current value of the HashMap, i.e. `null` and only then sets the value in the Hashmap to `jsonObject.getString("qty")`